# DateTime to string, formatting a line break into string while preserving culture

Tags: c#, datetime, globalization

I have a timestamp that I would like to represent as two lines. Currently, I am using "timeStamp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy \n hh:mm:ss tt")."

I would like to preserve the culture for this so that, when globalization is a concern, this time stamp is displayed correctly.

Is there a simple way to achieve this? Or, do I need to do something like... string.Format("{0}\n{1}", timeStamp.Date.ToString(), timeStamp.Time.ToString() ); ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want it displayed the same regardless of `CurrentCulture`, or do you want it to be flexible?

Comment: I would like it to display as en-US on a US-locale computer (so mm/dd/yyyy) and on non-US I would expect it to run as (dd/mm/yyy) or that locale's standard. I believe this means I want it to be flexible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to format a [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) value in a custom way:

```
string result = string.Format("{0:d}\n{0:T}", timestamp);

// result == "6/15/2009\n1:45:30 PM" (en-US)
// result == "15.06.2009\n13:45:30"  (de-DE)
```

Comment: If you really want to get picky it would be `String.Format("{1:d}{0}{1:T}", Environment.NewLine, timestamp)`. Note that as a (self-imposed) rule I always make the newline argument #0 when formatting with newlines.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to preserve the culture information, the easiest way to do this is to use your own example.

```
string.Format("{0}\r\n{1}", timeStamp.ToShortDateString(), timeStamp.ToLongTimeString());
```